# I got problem when run npm install, "verb lock using..."

Tags: node.js

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Full Error:

```
extract:passport-amazon: verb lock using C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-895550aa77ea655c.lock for C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ReactJs
```

Comment: Try using `cmd` instead of `PowerShell`, as well as running `npm cache clear --force`

Comment: Please make sure you're not behind a proxy, or else you need to set proxy for npm.

Answer (score -2):

Tried using Git Bash Here & it worked. Thanks

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: It seems that you are saying thanks for a previously posted (though meanwhile deleted) answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68743464/7733418 . That confuses me, because you should be unable to see it... If you are unaware of that answer please [edit] this according to [answer]. Or at least add a comment here to explain what you are thanking for, ideally with an unambiguous reference.